# Is there a onLogin hook for Craft3?

Tags: php, craftcms

I have searched high and low in the Docs and come up with nothing. I think I may not be using the right terminology.

But how do I register an `Event` in Craft 3 to execute when the user logs in? Something like this;

```
Event::on(
    Users::class,
    Users::EVENT_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    function (Event $event) {
        //code
    }
);
```

I notice there is `UsersController::EVENT_LOGIN_FAILURE` but nothing related to a successful login.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent to onLogin hook would be creating this exact event:

```
Event::on( \yii\web\User::class,  
        \yii\web\User::EVENT_AFTER_LOGIN, 
        function( \yii\web\UserEvent $event) {
         // your action goes here.  
});
```